# Need to start docker-compose up for a container with ubuntu 22.04 without internet access

Tags: docker, offline

I have docker compose and I have already container with ubuntu 22.04 which includes Nodejs app. Now, while connecting to internet it runs successfully, but when there is no internet access it does not run.
Question: How to disable the auto updates in ubuntu, so that when there is no internet access, it keeps using the existing packages and run the Node js successfully?

Thanks,

Comment: Hello and welcome to askubunt. Are you sure, that Ubuntu auto-updates are your issue? Neither docker nor container in general require a internet connection - but if your nodejs app requires internet... than it wont work without it

Comment: Yes, sure. The scenario is: the machine hosting docker & docker-compose was connecting to the internet, the docker-compose was running and starting the container normally. Now ,machine is disconnected, and the image which is already loaded in docker should be used without requesting internet. In docker-compose.yml file there is no image tag, but in DockerFile there is "FROM ubuntu:22.04". So what should be done  in order to use the already registered image and do not request internet anymore? OR, Maybe there is some config in the ubuntu to stop requesting internet for auto updates??

Comment: That is exactly what I don't understand: neither docker nor docker-compose are updating cached images. Its the opposite, e.g. you need the `--no-cache` and or `--pull` switch to force updates